# Problema con comando Powershell

Tags: cmd, github, netbeans-8.2, powershell

Tengo que clonar un proyecto en GitHub, y cuando abrí la terminal Powershell (como Administrador)...y cuando me posiciono en la carpeta que quiero que baje el proyecto y me sale el siguiente error:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32>cd D:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects
Set-location : No se encuentra ningún parámetro de posición que acepte el argumento 'Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects'. 
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ cd D:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Antes bajaba los proyectos sin problemas PERO ahora no...¿Cómo puedo solucionar dicho error?

Answer (score 1):

la solución fue agregar entre comillas la ruta de la carpeta a la que quería acceder (repuesta dada en el foro de Windows en Español)

https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/forum/all/problema-con-powershell-windows-10/e2b09bcf-c863-40da-ae82-8935a6301314

Comment: Por favor no coloques agradecimientos en tus respuestas pues no son necesarios, otra recomendación edita y coloca el enlace a la fuente original de donde obtuviste la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

```
PS C:\Windows\system32>cd D:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects
```

Este error se debe a que estas tratando de acceder a una carpeta en una ruta donde no esta

debes de navegar por las rutas en la consola hasta llegar a `NetBeansProjects` hay es donde debes de lanzar el comando `git clone 'url'`